pytesseract WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied I tried downloading and reinstalling, changing the folder, nothing worked
I have installed pytesseract in Windows 10 system. When I try to run the code It throws an error saying:
hp, ht, pid, tid = \_winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,

PermissionError: \[WinError 5\] Access is denied

Even after changing the tesseract_cmd path, it throws the same error.
Looking for the other possible ways to sort this issue.
# Import the necessary libraries
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

# Defining path to the Tesseract executable
path_to_tesseract =r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR'

# Path to the image you would be using
image_path = r"C:\cyberproject\picture\picai.png"
# Opening the image & storing it in an image object
img = Image.open(image_path)

# Providing the Tesseract executable location to pytesseract library
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract
# Passing the image object to image_to_string() function
# This function will extract the text from the image
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
# Displaying the extracted text
print(text)

I tried downloading and reinstalling, changing the folder, nothing worked.

not a great solution but have you tried running as administrator yet? also see this

i did, it did not work, but thank you!
